# asp classic FormatNumber bidding script

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Afternoon,

Im playing around with a little bidding script im trying to write. But im having trouble with formatNumber function.

```
currentBid = 50.51 'from database dataType double(16,2)
yourBid = isNumeric(Request("bid"))

If FormatNumber(yourBid,2) > FormatNumber(currentBid,2) Then
  Response.Write"bid successful... woop woop"
      else
  Response.Write"you cant bid below the current asking price"
end if
```

But if i was to bid 1000 is writes "you cant bid below the current asking price"

Please advise

Regards
Shane

```
 'Changed as advised

 currentBid = 50.51 'value from database

 If IsNumeric(Request.Form("bid")) Then
 yourBid = CDbl(Request.Form("bid"))
 end if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues here:

1. As Ekkehard mentioned, `IsNumeric()` returns a boolean. To test if the value is numeric and then store to your variable, use:

   ```
   If IsNumeric(Request("bid")) Then yourBid = CDbl(Request("bid"))
   ```
2. `FormatNumber()` returns a *string* representation of a number. So you're comparing one string against another instead of one number against another. If you need to round your numbers to two decimals, use the `Round()` function instead:

   ```
   If Round(yourBid,2) > Round(currentBid,2) Then
   ```

**Edit:** Proof.

```
MsgBox VarType(4)                ' 2 = vbInteger
MsgBox VarType(FormatNumber(4))  ' 8 = vbString
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
yourBid = isNumeric(Request("bid"))
```

does **not** store a valid number into `yourBid`, but the (booelan) result of the IsNumeric() function applied to `Request("bid")`.

Change the line to

```
yourBid = CDbl(Request("bid"))
```

and see if your IF statement works as expected. Then add a proper validation for `Request("bid")`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, ya it was a rookie mistake on my behalf. changed it now it works. I used... if isNumeric(Reuqest.Form("bid)) Then yourBid = CDbl(Request("bid")) hence the booelan. cheers guys.